# cant center image after wrapping it with div ? html

Tags: css, html, center

i need to center image horizontally , it should be very simple, i just use margin:auto. and it works , as you can see bellow.

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">


<head>


<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
 integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7"
 crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
.center_image {
 margin: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}
</style>


<style>
</style>

</head>
<body>

 <!-- carousel section -->
 <div class="container carosel_section" id="carosel_section">

  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
   <!-- Indicators -->
   <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
   </ol>

   <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
   <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active" style="height: 100%;">

     <img style="height: 100%"
      class="img-thumbnail img-responsive center_image"
      src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/05/46/63/0546638b58d2d396f97ad69177f104fa.jpg">



    </div>

   </div>


  </div>
 </div>


</body>
</html>
```

but when i wrapp the image with div, it isn't placed in center. as you can see here.

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">


<head>


<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
 integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7"
 crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
.center_image {
 margin: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}
</style>


<style>
</style>

</head>
<body>

 <!-- carousel section -->
 <div class="container carosel_section" id="carosel_section">

  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
   <!-- Indicators -->
   <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
   </ol>

   <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
   <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active" style="height: 100%;">
     <div class="carousel_item_grow_image"
      style="height: 100%; width: 100%; background-color: blue;">
      <img style="height: 100%"
       class="img-thumbnail img-responsive center_image"
       src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/05/46/63/0546638b58d2d396f97ad69177f104fa.jpg">

     </div>


    </div>

   </div>


  </div>
 </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @nevermind thank you for your comment. but they aren't not . please have look again. i've changed the image to smaller one which shows the differences.

Comment: yes, i see now. Put: text-align: center on wrapper div (carousel_item_grow_image, i think)

Comment: sometimes it is the simplest solution the correct one :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `display:inline-block;` from class `.img-thumbnail` or change it to `display:block;`

```
.img-thumbnail {
  display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should center `div` with image.
But you add class to image so you centered image in the `div`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works for me

```
.center_image {
  position:relative;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

If it not works on image, try on div. :)

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix, just add `text-align:center` to div like;

```
<div class="carousel_item_grow_image" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; background-color: blue; text-align:center">
```

Here is the demo https://jsfiddle.net/wxpjorfw/